# JQuery: How to change the "image.png" part of the src attribute of an img

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to simply change an image when a particular credit card schema is detected.

So, my code starts with this:

```
         <div class="form-group cc-number-group">
            <label for="cc-number" class="control-label">Card number <small class="text-muted">[<span class="cc-brand"></span>]</small></label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input style="border-right: 0;" id="cc-number" type="tel" size="20" data-stripe="number"  class="form-control cc-number card-generic form-control input-sm" autocomplete="cc-number" />
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <img height="16px" class="credit-card-icon" src="/bundles/bundlename/images/credit.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

After a lot of tries and fails, I wrote this code:

```
    switchCreditCardIcon = function(vendor) {
        var path = $('.credit-card-icon').attr('src').split('/');
        path.pop(-1);
        path.push(vendor + '.png');
        newPath = document.domain + path.join('/');
        $('.credit-card-icon').attr('src', path);
    };
```

So, for example, if I enter a Visa credit card, the new `vendor` is "visa".

Now, if i do `console.log(newPath)` the console logs `127.0.0.1/bundles/bundlename/images/visa.png` but the `src` attribute is set as `,bundles,bundlename,images,visa.png` so i receive an error:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/path/to/page/,bundles,bundlename,images,visa.png 404 (Not Found)

But, apart from the errors, maybe there is a simpler way of doing this... Can anyone give me some advice on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 newPath = document.domain + path.join('/');
 $('.credit-card-icon').attr('src', path);
```

You set `newPath` to the path joined with `/` and even included that in your `console.log(newPath)`, but then you set the src to `path` instead. I believe it should be:

```
$('.credit-card-icon').attr('src', newPath);
```

Comment: -.-' Thank you, maybe I'm jaded... Anyway, I also added `document.location.origin` to get the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

**JSBIN-URL** :[**JS-BIN**](http://jsbin.com/ramimurojo/edit?html,js,output)

`equals` is more faster better than `push` and `pop` in array

**JQUERY**

```
  ctr=0;
    $('button').click(function(){
      var t =$('input').val();
      $('p').html(t);
      arr= t.split('/');
      arr[arr.length-1]=ctr+".pmg";
      newPath=arr.join("/")
      $('p').html(newPath);
      ctr++;
    });
```

**HTML**

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
     <input type="text"/>
     <button>OK</button>
     <p></p>
```